# android/java concept to call all getter methods with a single loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, getter

I am doing an assignment and stuck at this point:
I have a class in which i have 30 getter and setter method.

```
  public class example{

public String get1(){
 return someString1;
}

public String get2(){
return someString1;
}

public String get3(){
return someString4;
}

and so on...

public String get30(){
return someString30;
}

}
```

Now i want to call all getter method with a single loop like

```
for(int i= 1; i<=30;i++){
// String total = get1()+get2()+get3()...............
}
```

what should i do?

**Edit:** i did it using reflection :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

**Thanks Ricky**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using reflection :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Answer (score 5):

The commented code is the only way to do that. But this is a symptom that your design is incorrect. Rather than having 30 properties of type `String`, you should certainly have one property of type `String[]` or `List<String>`.

Then you could do:

```
List<String> list = getListOfStrings();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : list) {
    builder.append(s);
}
String concatenation = builder.toString();
```

Comment: +1, and it preserves encapsulation - if the only thing needed is the concatenation of all strings, no need to "expose" the 30 string bits through getters - another thing, this is tagged as "homework", you shouldn't have included the actual solution in your post, just basic directions to solve it ;)

Answer (score 2):

If these are the standard accessors then better to go for `List` and do `get(index)`

else Reflection hack will help

```
public class Example{

  private List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

---

now loop

```
for(int i= 1; i<=30;i++){
   total += marks.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override the toString() method in the example class like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return someString1 + "  " + someString2 + "  " + someString3;
}
```